# Prisma generated types can hinder changing the database layer later on?

Tags: design-patterns, nestjs, typeorm, prisma, open-closed-principle

I recently heard about `prisma` and wanted to try it. I really liked the simple interface it provides and the level of type saftey. however, I have one question. when we use `prisma` to query an entity, the response we get has a type that comes from `@prisma/client` ( prisma generated ). Though it has some advantages but this is where I think that a violation of open closed principle can occur. In the future if I want to change the database layer or the orm to `typeorm` then all the return types of my service methods have to be changed to reflect my entities (rather than previously prisma generated types). Think of it in context of nestjs where we have entities that are our common return types. Is there a way we can solve this problem with prisma? Or it is not a problem at all?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the only way I see is creating your own custom types that just include Prisma's types as a layer. For e.g.

```
type UserWithPosts = Prisma.UserGetPayload<{
  include: { posts: true }
}>
```

Prisma's type system is more advanced than something like TypeORM where you can type the outputs like this quite easily. So in case you even want to change your ORM later, you just need to change these types to the one that the ORM supports.